# Amnesia running very slowly

Tags: graphics

So I installed Amnesia The Dark Descent and everything seemed fine until I made it to making a profile and starting screen. It ran very slowly and I couldn't even move the mouse and had to restart the computer. Maybe it's about my graphics card ? I have a nVidia Corporation MCP61 High Definition Audio graphics card.. Thanks ! :)

Comment: you install this, how? Did you try playonlinux ( it's already in the repository ) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, you probably mixed something up there. "nVidia Corporation MCP61 High Definition Audio" isn't a graphics card but your sound card. What graphics card you really have is displayed in the "system details" panel. Just type "details" into the dash and it should show up.

If you do have a nvidia or AMD graphics card you probably haven't installed the right graphics driver. Just run the driver installation tool and try installing the proprietary driver for your card. The app should show up when you type "jockey" into the dash.

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty much a beginner at this. GeForce 6150SE nForce 430/PCI/SSE2/3DNOW! Is that the graphics card ? It should work okay, some other games have worked very well with it...

Comment: Don't worry about it! :) And yes, that would be your graphics card. You should try activating the proprietary driver as I described in my answer. Other games that are graphically not very complex can run with the standard open source drivers. Games that are graphically more demanding - like Amnesia -  almost always need the proprietary driver installed though.

Comment: Thanks ! :) But I have 6 different drivers available, which one should I choose ? Picture here : http://i50.tinypic.com/2mgjtvn.png        
Graafikakiirenduse driver means the same as accelerated graphics driver.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a Nvidia graphics card and Google didn't bring anything up either. I'd say, just try them one after the other. (Don't forget to reboot everytime after you selected another one.) One of these six is probably going to work. Good luck! (And greetings to Estonia!:))

Comment: It's ok, I'll try then. And thank you very much for all the help ! :)